# Cannot checkout my repository, which is located under google cloud

Tags: linux, svn, google-cloud-platform

I wanted to install subversion to my google cloud linux server as following guide

https://www.vultr.com/docs/how-to-setup-an-apache-subversion-svn-server-on-centos-7

When I try to clone repository over server(Centos-7) have error

```
http authorization required
realm: Kuka Entertainment Repository Server
url: http://IP.IP.IP.IP/svn/ElementBall
 HTTP Error: 403 (Forbidden)
```

I have already checked capitalcase issues and anyother.

checked logs and the error is `Failed to load the AuthzSVNAccessFile: Can't open file '/svn/authz': Permission denied`

Conf

```
<Location /svn>
DAV svn
SVNParentPath /svn
AuthName "Kuka Entertainment Repository Server"
AuthType Basic
AuthUserFile /etc/svn/svn-auth
AuthzSVNAccessFile /svn/authz
Require valid-user
</Location>
```

Authz file

```
[groups]
admin=user001

[/]
@admin=rw
```

Comment: Check the logs on the server side. You can enable them as described at http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.serverconfig.httpd.html#svn.serverconfig.httpd.extra.logging After reading my answer and your questions several times I think that I am not sure why you get` 403 Forbidden` - checking server logs should help.

Comment: @bahrep checked logs `Failed to load the AuthzSVNAccessFile: Can't open file '/svn/authz': Permission denied`
Wow I already tried that, using centos7 is not user of apache?

Comment: see the new answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

During a long time search, I have found reason.
Disable selinux.

```
sudo vi /etc/selinux/config

#edit below line as
SELINUX=enforcing
#to
SELINUX=disabled
```

and reboot server

Answer (score 0):

The error `Failed to load the AuthzSVNAccessFile: Can't open file '/svn/authz': Permission denied` means that the user account that runs the Apache service does not have read permissions to the `/svn/authz` file. Therefore Apache can't read the permission list. Adjust the permissions.

Comment: `user account that runs the Apache service does not have read permissions to the /svn/authz file.` sorry but this is not leading anywhere, apache user is running httpd and its the owner of the folder and have rwx permissions

Comment: @ÖmrümÇetin the error tells a different story - Apache cannot read the file due to insufficient permissions.

Comment: how come its still giving same error to chmod 777 /svn/autz ? @bahrep

Comment: @ÖmrümÇetin IDK, maybe Apache runs as another user.